# Taking values from arrays using index doesn't work - XSL

Tags: xslt

I have created array like below.

```
<xsl:variable name="dispatchLiTotal" as="element()*">
    <xsl:for-each select=" /*/invoice/invline">
        <xsl:if test="/sbo/invoice/invline/deliverytotal">
            <xsl:for-each select="deliverytotal">
                <xsl:value-of select="subtotal" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Later in my code I am taking values from it but I am able to take only
"string concat" like this 171.15136.92128.99128.99126.00131.15124.611

```
<xsl:value-of select="$dispatchLiTotal" />
```

> Is returning 171.15136.92128.99128.99126.00131.15124.611

```
<xsl:value-of select="$dispatchLiTotal[1]" />
```

> Is returning error:
> javax.xml.transform.TransformerException:
> java.lang.ClassCastException: class
> org.apache.xpath.objects.XRTreeFrag cannot be cast to class
> org.apache.xpath.objects.XNodeSet (org.apache.xpath.objects.XRTreeFrag
> and org.apache.xpath.objects.XNodeSet are in unnamed module of loader
> 'app')

My expectation is that index[1] return 171.15

XML structure.

```
<sbo>
<invoice>
    <invline>
    </invline>
    <invline>
        <deliverytotal>
            <subtotal>171.15</subtotal>
        </deliverytotal>
    </invline>
    <invline>
    </invline>
    <invline>
        <deliverytotal>
            <subtotal>136.92</subtotal>
        </deliverytotal>
    </invline>
</invoice>
```

How should I do that?

Comment: Can you change to an XSLT 2 or 3 processor like Saxon 9 or 10? The use of `as` suggests you are trying to use XSLT 2 or 3, the error comes from Xalan, an XSLT 1 processor.

Comment: So in your opinion my code is going to work but I have to change version/engine right?

Comment: No, not quite, you would get a type error with XSLT 2 but if you used `copy-of` instead of `value-of` it would work with XSLT 2. It should probably be easier to just use something like `<xsl:variable name="dispatchLiTotal" select="/*/invoice/invline/deliverytotal/subtotal"/>`, perhaps with a predicate to express the `xsl:if` in pure XPath, to avoid the problem. But you haven't shown us the structure of the XML.

Comment: Right. Structure of the XML has been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you simply want to select input elements as a sequence or node-set with e.g. `<xsl:variable name="dispatchLiTotal" select="/*/invoice/invline/deliverytotal/subtotal"/>`, then `$dispatchLiTotal[1]` selects the first element in the sequence or node-set. That would work the same in XSLT 2/3 or 1, only that technically in XSLT 2/3 you are dealing with a sequence while in XSLT 1 it is a node-set.

Comment: It works! Wow.. it was that simple for real? :) Thanks a lot! Have a great day!